# Custom legend in rCharts (highcharts)

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
## Data
df <- data.frame(label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                 color = c("red", "red", "blue", "green"), 
                 y = c(10, 11, 12, 13))
```

"A" and "B" are part of the same category, while "C" and "D" are part of separate categories.

**I would like to add a legend on the chart with category labels.**

```
## Highchart without Legend

## Basic highchart
h <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
h$chart(type = "column")

## Highchart data:
h$series(showInLegend = FALSE, data =  rCharts::toJSONArray2(df[, c("label", "color", "y")], json = FALSE, names = TRUE))

## Highchart options:
h$xAxis(categories = unique(df$label), labels = list(rotation = 0, align = 'center', style = list(fontSize = '12px', fontFamily = 'Verdana, sans-serif')), replace = FALSE)
h$tooltip(formatter = "#! function() {return this.x + ': ' + this.y; } !#")
h$plotOptions(series = list(color = df$color), column = list(grouping = FALSE))
h  # display highchart
```

[image]

I haven't found a method that makes any sense to solve this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's how I solved it.

Each 'category' is split into a separate series with an x value to determine its location on the graph (highcharts requires this for some reason. Without it, the graphs stack).

Here's a sample code that works:

```
## Highchart with Legend
## Remark: simply switching showInLegend to TRUE will not work
df$x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3) # add an index to dataframe (starting from 0)
                      # and pass it to h$series data
h <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
h$chart(type = "column")
h$series(name = "Category 1 (Red)", color = "red", data = rCharts::toJSONArray2(df[df$color == "red", c("label", "color", "x", "y")], json = FALSE, names = TRUE))
h$series(name = "Category 2 (Blue)", color = "blue", data = rCharts::toJSONArray2(df[df$color == "blue", c("label", "color", "x", "y")], json = FALSE, names = TRUE))
h$series(name = "Category 3 (Green)", color = "green", data =  rCharts::toJSONArray2(df[df$color == "green", c("label", "color", "x", "y")], json = FALSE, names = TRUE)) 
h$xAxis(categories = unique(df$label), labels = list(rotation = 0, align = 'center', style = list(fontSize = '12px', fontFamily = 'Verdana, sans-serif')), replace = FALSE)
h$tooltip(formatter = "#! function() {return this.x + ': ' + this.y; } !#")
h$plotOptions(series = list(color = df$color), column = list(grouping = FALSE))
h # display chart
```

[image]

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I know the question says `rCharts`, I just want to add an alternative using highcharter package.

Like @Optimus said, the issue is add multiples series. In case you have arbitraty number of series (colors in your example) and want add it automatically you can use [`highcharter`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/index.html) with allow you to add multiples series from a list of data series with the `hc_add_series_list` function.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                 color = c("red", "red", "blue", "green"), 
                 y = c(10, 11, 12, 13),
                 x = c(1:4)-1)

head(df)

series <- df %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% # each serie is from one color
  do(data = list.parse3(.)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(name = paste("I'm color", color)) %>% 
  list.parse3()
```

Here `list.parse3` is similar to `toJSONArray2`.

```
series[[1]]

$color
[1] "blue"

$data
$data[[1]]
$data[[1]]$label
[1] "C"

$data[[1]]$color
[1] "blue"

$data[[1]]$y
[1] 12

$data[[1]]$x
[1] 2

$name
[1] "I'm color blue"
```

Finally:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(series) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$label) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(grouping = FALSE))
```

The result will be:

[image: result]

Comment: I know that you are the [dev of highcharter](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/25312?m=31229611#31229611), But however, when you are using the package, link to the [CRAN Page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/index.html) first and then to the homepage. There have been cases on meta where users flagged a legitimate answer as "overpromotion" thinking that the user was promoting some package. The general users might not be knowing that you are the dev of the package. Just take care the next time and apologies if I have erred in this. Regards

Comment: @BhargavRao, Totally agree. Make sense. In fact is in part propotion to communicate about about other package with makes easier some task (in this case add multiples data series). I'll edit the response to link CRAN site and move the homepage at the end of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that, Do visit the [R Public](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) chatroom, whenever you are free. It's a public chat where we help new users learn R. (There was an issue with a new user using highcharter yesterday, which was sorted out).

Comment: @jbkunst I have a factor with 11 levels, and would like 5 of them "on" but 6 of them "off" in my column chart / legend.  Gray, but still present in the legend so the series can be turned on if need be....is there an easier way to do that these days, since this was written ~1y ago?

Comment: @jbkunst don't see such an option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.title

Comment: @d8aninja If you want, let's talk in a gh issue with a reproducilble example and more details if  you want.